# JavaScript sorting of an RGB array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

This is the task:

Colors have to be ordered in such way:

- Higher Red value first; if the same then:
- Higher Green value first; if the same then:
- Higher Blue value first; if the same then on the same position

The task is as follows. I don't know how to do it or what it is supposed to look like. Ideally, the function should take an array of colors in HEX. E.g:

```
  [

    "#FF1100",

    "#44FF00",

    "#1900FF",

    "#E02500",

    "#54E600",

    "#0206DE",

   ]
```

And then it returned the sorted array as in the task. How can I do it? I am stuck.

Comment: *"I absolutely don't know how to do it"*: did you know that JavaScript has a `sort` method for arrays? It also takes an optional callback. What have you tried? What is the issue?

Comment: I was overcomplicated this task, i can't even try sort hex values i didn't even think that this can work, that output of that will be good

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simple sort with `reverse` should work:

`yourData.sort().reverse()`

Comment: OMG! I didn't know that sort() is working on HEX. Thank you so so so much!!!

Comment: sort() doesn't work on hex per se. Sort works on strings by default. Your hex values are actually strings, that's why it works :D

Comment: `sort` applies a default sort mechanism (a simple comparison) at array items which apparently works with/for string values.